# How to use toJson and fromJson method to map through a cart in Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider

I have a cart and I want to assign my cart items to my *_items* variable inside my Provider.
This is my method. I don't know if I should use toJson() or fromJson() methods:

This is the variable and the function inside the provider:

```
Map<String, CartItem> _items = {};
void getItems()async {
    var newItems = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(userId).collection("Cart").get();
    _items = newItems; // The error occurs here
}
```

***Error:***

> A value of type 'QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, CartItem>'.
> Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Map<String, CartItem>'.

**CartModel.dart**

```
class CartItem {
  String? id;
  String? title;
  String? price;
  int? qty;
  String? image;

  CartItem({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.price,
    required this.qty,
    required this.image,
  });

  CartItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    image = json['image'];
    price = json['price'];
    qty = json['qty'] as int;
    // totalprice = double.parse(json['totalprice']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['image'] = this.image;
    data['price'] = this.price;
    data['qty'] = this.qty;
    // data['totalprice'] = this.totalprice;

    return data;
  }
}
```

Because I want to use it here (no space to. I will share a snippet):

[image]

Comment: Still need help?

Comment: YES please , https://github.com/Y7gn/Flutter_resturant_project1 you may check my repository for more info

Comment: Hey, an specific reason `Map<String, CartItem> _items = {};` is a map instead of `List<CartItem> _items =[];`

Comment: You are right , i just want to fix the error , what should i do

Answer (score 0):

I think toJson is if you're trying to send it out as json. From json is if you expect to receive that data (like an API get request).

The error comes from you declaring _items to be of type Map<String, CartItem> but in the CartModel class, it is expected to come in as as Map of string to string.

Comment: how can fix the error exactly in the model class , i didn't use either toJson() or fromJson() methods

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `fromjson` method should return a class instance.
2. You are not converting your firebase output.

Below is your updated class:

```
class CartItem {
  String? id;
  String? title;
  String? price;
  int? qty;
  String? image;

  CartItem({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.price,
    required this.qty,
    required this.image,
  });

  factory CartItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
   
    return CartItem(
    id: json['id'],
    title: json['title'],
    image: json['image'],
    price: json['price'],
    qty: json['qty'] as int,
);
    // totalprice = double.parse(json['totalprice']);
  }

  Map<String,dynamic> toJson(){
    final Map<String,dynamic> data = new Map<String,dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['image'] = this.image;
    data['price'] = this.price;
    data['qty'] = this.qty;
    // data['totalprice'] = this.totalprice;

    return data;
  }
}
```

> A value of type 'QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, CartItem>'.

Now to fix the above error, we have to convert `QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>` to `Map<String, CartItem>`.

**Note:** I'll use `List<CartItem>` instead of `Map<String, CartItem>`.

```
List<CartItem> _items = [];

void getItems()async{
    var newItems = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(userId).collection("Cart").get();
 for (var element in newItems.docs){
 _items.add(CartItem.fromJson(element.data());
  
}
```

This code was not tested.